# how to send notification based on users location oneSignal

Tags: php, laravel, onesignal

So I have this function that I want it to send notifications based on user location using OneSignal REST API, it's my first time dealing with notification and one-signal, so I check https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs I spend the last 7 H trying  :(, what I found is I can sort my audience using filters, fortunately, I didn't understand How to use it, sorry if my English not clear enough, thanks in advance 
my_function

```
public function sendNotification(){
   $content = array(
        "en" => 'Test Message'
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "My_app_id",
        'filters' => array(array("field" => "location", "key" => "radius", "relation" => "=", "value" => "50"),array("operator" => "or"),array("field" => "location", "key" => "lat", "relation" => "=", "value" => "3.1946047"),array("operator" => "or"),array("field" => "location","key"=>"long", "relation" => "=", "value" => "30.2402744")),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic NmZhZDk4MDMtZTJlZ'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $return["allresponses"] = $response;
    return $return = json_encode( $return);


}
```

Comment: What is the response when you try your request?

Comment: very clear documentation of oneSignal package for Laravel: https://laravel-notification-channels.com/onesignal/#usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not formatted as requested in the doc:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#send-to-users-based-on-filters

This corrected `'filters'` will filter all users within a radius of a certain location:

```
        $fields = array(
            'app_id' => "My_app_id",
            'filters' => [
                [
                    "field" => "location", 
                    "radius" => "50", 
                    "lat" => "3.1946047", 
                    "long" => "30.2402744"
                ]
            ],
            'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
            'contents' => $content
        );
```

Comment: Yes my code is not formatted as mentioned in Docs I didn't get the syntax correctly , I updated my code and its works as expected, thanks for help

Comment: Very good! if this answers your question, please accept my answer so it can help others as well.

Comment: it solves it and I did accept your answer thanks buddy

Comment: You're very welcome! Feel free to ask more if you need help 